# Bacbone Marionette composing a complex composite view

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I am trying to create a page which contains a "Form" and a "Grid". Consider a standard usecase of data filter and resulting data table below.

For creating this kind of page, I am struggling to apply my marionette knowledge.

I am sure I need a composite view for the datatable. But then how do I put rest of the content which includes another potentially composite view for the filtering form content?

I think I need a composite view containing another composite view. But that seems incorrect since composite view dictates that the itemView must repeat 'n' no of times. and here I do not have a repeating case really.

I have read through [David Sulk's tutorial](http://davidsulc.com/blog/2013/02/03/tutorial-nested-views-using-backbone-marionettes-compositeview/), [Derrik's tutorials](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/03/22/managing-layouts-and-nested-views-with-backbone-marionette/).. But could not apply their thoughts to my problem.

Can someone guide me?

--Vijay

Comment: I don't use marionette but it seems it sounds like this can be solved by using events. assume you have a collection which contains your search results, pass it to both views. When you change the search criteria in the form, apply it to the collection and fetch results, in your Grid view, listen to the collection's 'reset' event, and rerender the results when the collection is reset.

Comment: I worked around the issue by creating an intermediate Layout-Region combination to divide the form and grid into separate parts of page. Post this, form became itemview and grid became composite view. Not sure if there is any other way.. or if this __IS__ the way.